# Quiz always tells the player he/she is correct

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple little quiz here, but whatever the user types, the user will always be told that they have the correct answer, even if it's wrong.

Here's my source codes:
The first class you see here is the Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TheQuiz
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Quiz! \nYou'll be asked 20 questions! If you get one question wrong, you'll be out.\nHowever if you answer all 20 questions correctly, you'll be the MASTER!");
        Console.WriteLine("\nLet us begin! Are you ready?\n\n");

        Console.WriteLine("(Remember, TYPE in the correct answer. Every answer has ONE word only!\nAnd ALWAYS use a capital letter at the beginning of the answer: 'Answer')\n\n(Press Enter to continue...)");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("In what country was Adolf Hitler born?");

        Console.ReadLine();

        if (Answers.AnswerOne.Equals("Austria"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! {0} is the correct answer!", Answers.AnswerOne);
        }
        else if (!Answers.AnswerOne.Equals(Answers.AnswerOne))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry! You wrote the wrong answer!\nThe correct answer was {0]", Answers.AnswerOne);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
}
```

Here is my other class, Answers.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TheQuiz
{
public class Answers
{

    public static string AnswerOne = "Austria";
    public static string AnswerTwo = "";
    public static string AnswerThree = "";
    public static string AnswerFour = "";
    public static string AnswerFive = "";
    public static string AnswerSix = "";
    public static string AnswerSeven = "";
    public static string AnswerEight = "";
    public static string AnswerNine = "";
    public static string AnswerTen = "";
    public static string AnswerEleven = "";
    public static string AnswerTwelve = "";
    public static string AnswerThirteen = "";
    public static string AnswerFourteen = "";
    public static string AnswerFifteen = "";
    public static string AnswerSixteen = "";
    public static string AnswerSeventeen = "";
    public static string AnswerEighteen = "";
    public static string AnswerNineteen = "";
    public static string AnswerTwenty = "";

}
}
```

So the correct answer is Austria, but if the user types anything else like Germany, it still shows that it is the correct answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it homework? If yes, then add appropriate tag please.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code do you store the user answer, you just write `Console.ReadLine();` and compare the correct answer with itself .

You Probably want something like

`string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();`

and then a comparison between the correct answer and the user answer

`if (Answers.AnswerOne.Equals(userAnswer))`

Note that the Equals method for string equality is character sensitive and case sensitive, so if the user types "Austria " or "austria", the program would tell them they are incorrect.

You avoid the case being sensitive by telling the comparison to use Case Insensitive Comparison , like by using `string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);`  or by converting both strings to the same case using `String.ToLower(string)` or `String.ToUpper(string)`.

You also need to change the else if to 
`else if (!Answers.AnswerOne.Equals(userAnswer))` or to just else in order to have the incorrect answer message be displayed when an incorrect answer is given.

Comment: Thanks a lot. About the case sensitive thing: How does one solve that?

Comment: Thank you. It helped and worked! But I noticed that something didn't work in my code: If the user writes the wrong answer, no message telling the user that it was wrong appears (which there should). I have placed a '!' operator infront of the code but it still doesn't work. Do you know how to solve this? Is there another operator?

Comment: Yes, I changed it to that and it didn't work. Unfortunately, changing it to only 'else' doesn't work either... I am completely stuck.

Comment: Nevermind I found the error! It was just a simple spelling mistake! Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: How do I move on to the next question once a user has answered the first question? Do I continue to code within that 'if' section where it says that the user has answered correctly, or is there a way to resume the code and let it move on to the next 'if' after the current one?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `Answers.AnswerOne` to `"Austria"`, which will *always* be true because *that's what it's set to.*

What you need to do is compare what you get from the user (from the `Console.ReadLine`) against `Answers.AnswerOne`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the value of console.readline into a string variable and then compare that to your answer1 value. Also, make sure you check case because c# is case senstive.

Answer (score 0):

Answers.AnswerOne.Equals("Austria") is always true.  Answers is the class you created that holds the correct Answers.

What you are not doing is storing the users response in a variable.  You are just reading it from the console but not keeping it for comparison.